# How to vectorize creating columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize the creation of a `data.frame` without repeatedly writing it as shown below? Basically I want to create huge numbers of columns and I am looking for shorter way.

```
QQ <- data.frame(rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100),rep(55,100))
names(QQ) <- sprintf("%s%02d", "S", c(1:16))
```

Rather than writing `rep(55,100)` many times I want to do it through vectorization (function otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rep` a 'list' object as the argument to `data.frame`:

```
> QQ <- data.frame(rep(list(rep(55,5)), 5))
> names(QQ) <- sprintf("%s%02d", "S", c(1:5))
> QQ
  S01 S02 S03 S04 S05
1  55  55  55  55  55
2  55  55  55  55  55
3  55  55  55  55  55
4  55  55  55  55  55
5  55  55  55  55  55
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about defining your rows and columns and `rep` the product of these into a matrix, using your columns to `dim` the matrix, then coerce to a `data.frame`:

```
#  Desired columns
nc <- 100
# Desired rows
nr <- 1e3

#  Turn matrix into data.frame (is this necessary - can you use a matrix - would be quicker)
QQ <- data.frame( matrix( rep( 55 , nc * nr ) , ncol = nc ) )
dim(QQ)
[1] 1000  100
names(QQ) <- sprintf("%s%02d", "S", c(1:nc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rep within rep:

```
QQ <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(rep(55,100),16),nrow=100,ncol=16))
names(QQ) <- sprintf("%s%02d", "S", c(1:16))
```